# T-SQL query to return specific Region and group all result for that Region by the first few characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I am trying to write a query in T-SQL to return specific results by Region, and group those results by the first several characters of the Region name.  I also need to group all results not like the Region name being searched for as Other.

```
   Region             Total 
USA Servers West      100
USA Servers East      400
Canada Servers        120
Europe Servers         80
Asia Servers           70
Mexico Servers         50
```

I need to group the USA Servers together as 1 Region, and when I search for USA and Canada Servers return the totals for them, but return the totals for all the other Regions as Other.

```
   Region          Total
USA Servers         500
Canada Servers      120
Others              200
```

What's the easiest way to get these results?

Comment: To refine my search to select just Canada Servers and Others, how would I do that task?  I need to select Others with another Region sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

One way to go about this would be to use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT   region, SUM(total) AS total
FROM     (SELECT CASE WHEN region LIKE 'USA Servers%' THEN 'USA Servers'
                      WHEN region LIKE 'Canada Servers%' THEN 'Canada Servers'
                      ELSE 'Others'
                 END AS region,
                 total
          FROM   servers) t
GROUP BY region
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution.  This worked perfectly for what I needed.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: To refine my search to select just Canada Servers and Others, how would I do that task?  I need to select Others with another Region sometimes.

Comment: @TugStrongly Add a `where region not like 'USA Servers%' clause to the inner query, and you could drop the `case` branch that handles them.

Answer (score 2):

```
select 'USA Servers',    sum(total) 
  from servers 
 where region like 'USA Servers%' 
union all
select 'Canada Servers', sum(total)
  from servers 
 where region like 'Canada Servers%'
union all
select 'Other Servers',  sum(total)
  from servers 
 where region not like 'USA Servers%'
   and region not like 'Canada Servers%'
```

Comment: Serial down vote on this and 3 old questions?  Grow up.